# Where can I find documentation on NumPy's delineation of its directories?

Tags: numpy

This may be a stupid question, but...

Where can I find a simple explanation of what goes under 'lib,' vs 'core'? How do I know whether a function goes under fromnumeric.py, or function_base.py? Some of the .py files have explanation strings at the beginning, but others do not.

Comment: Most `numpy` functions are available without the `lib` or `core` reference.  A few modules require a special import, such as `from numpy.lib import recfunctions`.  Usually I just use the `ipython` `??` to look at the code and see the source file.  The function `docs` also have `[source]` link.  Sometimes the `ipython` tab complete helps.  To dig further I explore the source on `github`.  I don't know of any simple explanation or comprehensive listing.  There's a lot of history behind the current organization.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. However, that ‘simple explanation or comprehensive listing’ is precisely what I’m after.

Comment: Why do you need it?  Just curiosity or do need the information for some programming purpose?

Comment: @hpaulj Curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

You may double check the [numpy/reference](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/) and [numpy/user](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/) guides.